# Date countdown based on user inputted date

Tags: datetime, button, countdown

How do I create an alert after clicking a submit button, that show how many days left to a departure date inputted on a form

Comment: Too many unknowns to give you a definitive answer. Please see [ask] and revise your question to include pertinent details. Asking a better question will get you better answers. Be sure to include (and tag) the tools and languages you are using to achieve this function.

Comment: If this is a web form, for instance, you should specify that somewhere AND include a [mcve]. Use tags like "HTML" and "javascript" or any other languages related to your issue to get this question in front of the right people.